# Contextual XmlSerialization

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Is there any way to control xml serialization for ex. checking properties in root/parent object.

I have:

```
class ClassA
{
    public int SomeAIntProp {get; set; }

    ClassB OtherClass;
}

class ClassB
{
    public int SomeBIntProp {get; set; }
}
```

This is what I want:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeSomeBIntProp(context) 
{ 
    return (context is ClassA) && ((ClassA)context).SomeAIntProp >10; 
}
```

}

Comment: How is that serialization?  Seems like you're trying to put logic in the wrong place.  How would this be serialized back into these classes?

Comment: One of the principles for writing good code is the Single Responsibility principle, which in its most basic form means a class should be responsible for only one thing. In trying to make your serialization perform object validation you are violating this, by doing more than 1 thing and I would say it is a bad design / idea.

Comment: @Joe the overall ShouldSerialize* pattern is well established - but doesn't support this subtlety.

Comment: @Kane as a DTO, it is not outside SRP to decide what should/shouldn't be included in the output

Comment: @user1009911 in which class do you propose that method?

Comment: @MarcGravell i would like to have this method in ClassB or some external object controling objects serialization.

Comment: @user1009911 could ClassB have a reference to ClassA (marked `[XmlIgnore]`)? If it could, then ClassB can just use that navigation

Comment: @MarcGravell i dont have any parent/child relationship and i cant add it.

Comment: @user1009911 then you cannot do what you want in any easy/clean way.

Comment: @MarcGravell maybe you know any libs that could help?

Comment: @user1009911 not for XML, I do not (and I know .NET serialization pretty well). If the format wasn't important I could add support in my own pet library, but that isn't XML and I suspect XML is fundamental to you.

Answer (score 1):

Not in any of the standard/inbuilt serializers, no. All of the logic must be relative to the instance being serialised (you can of course walk any navigation properties that already exist - `.Parent` etc - although that would need to be marked `[XmlIgnore]`). The only other option is to implement `IXmlSerializable` and do it all manually, but I strongly advise against that.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do it in `Serialization`, but simply add to your class a function that first validate the content to be saved and after calls concrete serialization function.

If you have more then one object that have to be combined and saved in single file, so also some cross validation against different type of objects that participate in serialization, you can or implement *SerializationAdapter* ( that your custom class has to combine, validate and serialize objects of interest), or use [Chain of Responsibility](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternChain.aspx), if it's possible in your case, where you have a set of functions throw which your objects have to pass and be validated, and some final function that validates final result of all functions on all objects you need. More or less like if your object(s) are patient(s) and validation functions are doctors, and finally you got a receipt, that based on every single analyse, reports you final result.

Hope this helps.

Comment: SerializationAdapter? Isn't that Java?

Comment: @Marc, it's class "concept" name, just to explain what I mean. I don't know Java and don't know if there is any, honestly.

Comment: Ah, my mistake then. As written, it reads (to me, at least) as a concrete thing, rather than conceptual - especially with the formatting suggesting an existing/actual type-name.